# CREATE TABLE con PHP, POST, mysql, html sintaxis

Tags: php, html, mysql, post

Necesito hacer que funcione este script. La idea es crear una tabla dentro de la base de datos, que pueda crear los atributos de un producto.
Creo que el error está en la sintaxis de la parte del script en donde intento crear la tabla, porque todo lo demás, funciona bien. El único resultado que me da es que abre el url de donde está alojado el script y con la página en blanco.

Les paso el código PHP:

```
<?php 
if (!empty($_POST)){
    if (isset($_POST["nombre"])) {
        if($_POST["nombre"]!=""){
            include "conexion.php";

            $found = false;
            $sql1 = "SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE table_name=\"$_POST[nombre]\"";
            $query = $con->query($sql1);
            while ($r=$query->fetch_array()) {
                $found = true;
                break;
            }
            if($found){
                print "<script>alert(\"El atributo ya está registrado.\");window.location='../index.php';</script>";
            }
            $sql = "CREATE TABLE focus.\"$_POST[nombre]\" (id int(11) not_null auto_increment primary key, nombre varchar(500) not_null, created_at datetime not_null);";
            $query = $con->query($sql);
            if($query!=null){
                print "<script>alert(\"Registro exitoso.\");window.location='../index.php';</script>";
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

He probado varias formas de escribir el script pero no logro encontrar la forma correcta.

Muchas gracias a todos por leer.
Saludos!

Comment: La Sintaxis es `NOT NULL` no lleva guión bajo, además para que utiliza `focus.` ? asumo que focus es el nombre de su bd y está ya se selecciona al momento de realizar la conexión

Comment: Así es, focus sería el nombre de la bd. Ya quité los guiones de los not null.
Todavía nada...

Comment: He añadido una respuesta explicando un poco los cambios que debe hacer para solucionar los errores de sintaxis. Si aún persisten los problemas, puede comentar mi respuesta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En primer lugar la sintaxis para un campo no nulo es `NOT NULL` sin guión bajo de separación.

Si desea crear una tabla con la sintaxis `nombredb.nombretabla` deberá encerrar el nombre entre comillas **`**

La sintaxis de la creación podría quedar.

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE `focus.".$_POST['nombre'] ."`
     (id int(11) not null auto_increment primary key, 
    nombre varchar(100) not null, 
    created_at datetime not null);";
```

> Añadir que deberá añadir una capa de seguridad a sus consultas, para
>   evitar problemas a futuro, un POST para iniciar puede ser [¿Cómo evitar la inyección SQL en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php)

Comment: Perfecto, gracias a esto ya quedó solucionado, ahora paso una respuesta de cómo dejé finalmente el script..
Todavía no estoy trabajando con las posibles inyecciones SQL, estoy armando un prototipo como para luego optimizarlo. Muchas gracias por las respuestas!

Comment: @JoseManuelBorras Qué bien, no olvide leer [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) , Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

debes hacerlo asi:

```
$nombre= filter_var($_POST[nombre], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$sql="CREATE TABLE focus.${nombre} (id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, nombre varchar(500) NOT NULL, created_at DATETIME NOT NULL);";
```

> nota debes sanear el nombre la variable pasado por post ya que si no estas propenso a un ataque por sqlinjection

Comment: sigue sin funcionar, la pagina queda en blanco en la url del script...

Comment: porque debe ser `if($query)` no `if($query != null)`

Answer (score 0):

Gracias a las respuestas, así quedó finalmente el script funcionando:

```
<?php 
if (!empty($_POST)){
    if (isset($_POST["nombre"])) {
        if($_POST["nombre"]!=""){
            include "conexion.php";

            $found = false;
            $sql1 = "SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE table_name=\"$_POST[nombre]\"";
            $query = $con->query($sql1);
            while ($r=$query->fetch_array()) {
                $found = true;
                break;
            }
            if($found){
                print "<script>alert(\"El atributo ya está registrado.\");window.location='../index.php';</script>";
            }
            $sql = "CREATE TABLE `".$_POST['nombre']."` (id int(11) not null auto_increment primary key, nombre varchar(100) not null, created_at datetime not null);";
            $query = $con->query($sql);
            if($query!=null){
                print "<script>alert(\"Registro exitoso.\");window.location='../index.php';</script>";
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

El problema estaba en los guiones bajos de los NOT NULL, y las comillas en el $_POST.
Si no me equivoco, son errores de sintaxis.

Aclaración: Soy muy nuevo en programación, así que más adelante me verán molestandolos con más cuestiones básicas, y luego tratando de evitar las inyecciones Mysql y demás problemas de seguridad.

Muchas gracias a todos por los aportes y respuestas.